# Javascript URL with Template String

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I would like to mount a URL string with Template String. I want to know if it is possible.

This is what I am doing:

```
let url = `http://example.com/
                              MY_SERVICE/
                              MY_CONTROLLER/
                              ${MY_FIRST_PARAM}/
                              ${MY_SECOND_PARAM}`;
```

This code will return a string with break lines.

My question is: Is this possible to to this without break lines? The purpose is to have a more readable code.

My real URL is a little bit bigger than this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call replace on any white space character after the template string:

```js
let MY_FIRST_PARAM = 'foo';
let MY_SECOND_PARAM = 'bar';

let url = `http://example.com/
  MY_SERVICE/
  MY_CONTROLLER/
  ${MY_FIRST_PARAM}/
  ${MY_SECOND_PARAM}`
  .replace(/\s/g, '');

console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 3):

In case this becomes useful to somebody else.
Here are notes from my own experience related to similar situation.

The question is originally about a long template string with new lines.
But the example also shows up about a system where one could store URLs and plug in parameters dynamically.

This is for people from the future who happens to try doing the same, either in relation to *URI Templates*, and/or template literals, and/or stripping off white-space/new-lines. Like I did today.

The author most likely implemented like he asked the question.

The pattern of having URLs we can configure and insert variables has a specification and tools to help you not re-invent that wheel. :-)

Besides, if you concatenate many template literals you [may get complaints from ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-template-curly-in-string).

A better way of doing is to leverage JavaScript's `URL` object and [RFC 6570 **URI Template** specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570)

It makes things much more manageable.

The implementation I used today was using [bramstein/url-template](https://github.com/bramstein/url-template).
This library is awesome and it supports [**a lot of use-cases**](https://github.com/uri-templates/uritemplate-test/blob/fdd5d611a849b922c2ff40fc3997fd265dd14c02/extended-tests.json#L28)

Here is a full-circle example of a *URI Template*, and how to manipulate the URL without using *RegExes*.

```js
// const urltemplate = require('url-template');
// Using example from question, slightly modified.
let url = `http://example.com/
                              MY_SERVICE/
                              MY_CONTROLLER
                              {/MY_FIRST_PARAM,MY_SECOND_PARAM}
                              `;
//                              (below) STRIP OFF new lines and spaces
//                               Credits to KevBot
const parsed = urltemplate.parse(url.replace(/[\s\n]/g,''));
const exampleFactory = a => new URL(parsed.expand(a))

// NOTICE we do not give any velue to MY_SECOND_PARAM
const firstExample = {
  MY_FIRST_PARAM: 'foo'
}
console.log((exampleFactory(firstExample)).pathname);
// > '/MY_SERVICE/MY_CONTROLLER/foo'

const secondExample = {
  MY_FIRST_PARAM: 'foo',
  MY_SECOND_PARAM: 'bar'
}
console.log((exampleFactory(secondExample)).pathname);
// > '/MY_SERVICE/MY_CONTROLLER/foo/bar'
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bramstein/url-template/c7119202/lib/url-template.js"></script>
```

<sub>*NOTE* Use of *URI* and *URL* is voluntarily mixed as we aren't talking about XML namespaces ("*URI*") that looks like a Web Address ("*URL*")</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You get line breaks because an ENTER with the "``" notation in javascript will cause a newline, as explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Simply write everything in the same line.

Comment: Hi, I did it, but the code was not very readable. In my case, I am using variables into string, so, the solution propose by @KevBot works very nice.